# How to remove caret symbol on Neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

Neovim is my main editor and I cannot get rid of the carets (`^`) when opening Nerdtree or even a normal file.

Take a look:

[image: This is a gitignore file]

---

[image]

Comment: `:help 'fillchars'`

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem was due to a theme I was using.

Switching to a different one fixed the problem.